# Spring MockMvc: Assert Json field is either an empty array or not existed

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm using [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) to test an API which returns JSON content, and that JSON may contain a field called **shares** as an empty array, or may not be existed at all (I mean **shares** field).

JSON sample:

```
{
    "id":1234,
     .....
    "shares":[]
}

//or

{
    "id":1234,
    ....
}
```

How can I assert that this field is either empty or not existed

like:

```
mvc.perform(
    post("....url.......")
        .andExpect(status().is(200))
        // I need one of the following to be true, but this code will assert both of them, so it will fail
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.shares").isEmpty())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.shares").doesNotExist())
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can check that the field does NOT exist in the json payload.

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldThatShouldNotExist").doesNotExist())
```

If you wanted to be able to test for if it exists and is empty OR it doesn't exist, you'd have to write your own custom Matcher to create an XOR like behavior. See this answer as a guide. [Testing in Hamcrest that exists only one item in a list with a specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609476/testing-in-hamcrest-that-exists-only-one-item-in-a-list-with-a-specific-property/29610402#29610402)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 
[JsonPath OR condition using MockMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869155/jsonpath-or-condition-using-mockmvc)

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.isPass", anyOf(is(false),is(true))));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
{ "arrayFieldName": [] }
```

You can use:

```
.andExpect( jsonPath( "$.arrayFieldName", Matchers.empty() );
```

that is cleaner.

Comment: This doesn't catch the case where the field is not in the json body.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the original question, I found this useful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch the case where the field isn't in the json body at all, you can use `doesNotHaveJsonPath()`:

```java
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldThatShouldNotExistOrEvenBeNull").doesNotHaveJsonPath())
```

So if your `shares` field isn't present in the body, this matcher will pass. If it is present, this matcher will fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsEmptyCollection.empty;

.andExpect(jsonPath("$.isPass",empty() ));
```

Comment: This doesn't catch the case where the field is not in the json body.